# Unable to pass User Model's first_name and last_name data to a template

Tags: django

I am trying to construct a user profile page for my project, hence I need to access to user Model's data like first_name and last_name. But for some reason I can access the username and email field but not the first_name and last_name. When I call these fields from my template, nothing displays.

```
<table class="table-responsive">
        <tr>
            <td>Username</td>
            <td>{{ user.get_username }}</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>First Name</td>
            <td>{{ user.first_name }}</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Last Name</td>
            <td>{{ user.last_name }}</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Email</td>
            <td>{{ user.email }}</td>
        </tr>
</table>
```

My profile_view.py

```
def profile_view(request):
    args = {'user' : request.user}
    return render(request, 'user_account/profile.html', args)
```

I've tried using the functions like user.get_full_name but that doesn't work either.

thanking you in advance.

Comment: Maybe `first_name ` and `last_name` field of every user is blank.

Comment: Thank you Satendra, that was exactly the problem. there is no problem with my code, the fields were blank from the db. To think about the time i have spent trying to figure out the solution to a problem that is not really a problem.

Answer (score -2):

Have you tried this?

```
def profile_view(request, id):
    user = User.objects.get(id=id)
    args = {'user' : user}
    return render(request, 'user_account/profile.html', args)
```